# TensorFlow: a subtlety about seed

Tags: tensorflow, random-seed

I want to seed my random number generator. I can do the following, which works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

# Set seed at graph-level
tf.random.set_random_seed(1)
# Set seed at op level
a = tf.random_uniform([1], seed=1)

with tf.Session() as sess1:
    print(sess1.run(a))
```

The following also works:

```
print(sess.run(tf.random_uniform([1], seed=1)))
```

However, the following generates a different number each time I run it:

```
print(sess.run(a))
```

Information about seed: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed

1) Why does the latter not work?

2) What can I do in order to make it work, i.e. without the use of "with tf.Session() as sess1:" ?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.random_uniform(..., seed=1)` does not mean to generate a same number all the time, but a same series of numbers within a session when executed multiple times. So the following will have same behavior:

```
sess = tf.Session()
a = tf.random_uniform([1], seed=1)
for _ in range(10):
    print(sess.run(a))

print('----------')

with tf.Session() as sess1:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(sess1.run(a))
```

Comment: What do I do in order to generate the same number all the time within a session?

Comment: How about generating a seeded random number and puting it in a `tf.Constant`?

Comment: I already new about this one. But I thought there should be a way to do it with tensorflow.

Comment: `a = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_uniform([1]))` this is what I can come up with.